# How fix 'permission denied' on the default /civicrm url in a new install?

Tags: installation

CiviCRM is generally working. The default myhost.com/civicrm url has a 'permission denied' error.

[image: Permission denied on the default url]

The dashboard when using the full link works

[image: CiviCRM dashboard]

Comment: I have not run into that, but the bare url page doesn't do anything in my experience anyway. You always have to have some additional element on the URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by setting the civicrm files directory be under /web/. The web server does not allow directory browsing.

Things that didn't work

- menu rebuild
- cache rebuild
- checking permissions
- comparing the installation
- overriding hook_toolbar
- debugging AccessManager.php

Looking at the web server error logs, and seeing that 403 was on the directory provided the hint.